# Create a new variables and save them, call them when needed

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I need help with my bachelor degree, Im not asking for a code but rather "point me" in the right direction. Basically I have a robotic arm with manual control. I need to record movements on x,y,z axes and then be able to call them.
Example: I will put something in position A, which has specific x,y and z. I will do the same with position b,c,d,e.... and I dont know where to find some guidance or tutorial how to make my code create a new variables and then call them.

Im trying to find someone with simlar code on all kinds of forums but so far I was unlucky